# CSS @Media Columns

Tags: css

I'm using CSS for text columns but I decided I wanted to change the number of columns dynamically based on screen size using CSS's @media.

So this:

```
.SetColumns {
    background: inherit;    
    padding: 0 20px 20px 20px;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-gap: 40px;
    -moz-column-rule: 3px double #666;
    -webkit-column-count: 2; 
    -webkit-column-gap: 40px;
    -webkit-column-rule: 3px double #666;
    column-count: 2;
    column-gap: 40px;
    column-rule: 3px double #666;
}
```

became this (column count removed):

```
.SetColumns {
    background: inherit;    
    padding: 0 20px 20px 20px;
    -moz-column-gap: 40px;
    -moz-column-rule: 3px double #666;
    -webkit-column-gap: 40px;
    -webkit-column-rule: 3px double #666;
    column-gap: 40px;
    column-rule: 3px double #666;
}
```

then I moved the column counts themselves to another included css file with:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 415px){
    .stdv {display: none;} /* Site menu */
    .LogoBar {display: none;}
    .TitleBar {height: 20px;}
    .PageContent {margin: -40px 0 150px 0;}
    .Logout {padding-left: 0;
             margin-left: 0;}
    div.UpdateDate {display: none;}
    .SetColumns {-moz-column-count: 1;
                  -webkit-column-count: 1;
                   column-count: 1;
                 }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px and (min-width: 416px){
    .SetColumns {-moz-column-count: 2;
                  -webkit-column-count: 2;
                   column-count: 2;
                 }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1919px) and (min-width: 1024px){
    .SetColumns {-moz-column-count: 3;
                  -webkit-column-count: 3;
                   column-count: 3;
                 }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1920px){
    .SetColumns {-moz-column-count: 4;
                  -webkit-column-count: 4;
                   column-count: 4;
                 }
}
```

but get only a single column no matter the browser size. Is there some rule in CSS that all the column tags need to be repeated for it to work or is there some other obvious error that I missed?

UPDATE: In order to make the columns work, I had to repeat the column tags in each @media which I was trying not to have to do. So getting rid of this and putting it into each of the @media tags work, it was not what I was trying to do.

```
.SetColumns {
    background: inherit;    
    padding: 0 20px 20px 20px;
    -moz-column-gap: 40px;
    -moz-column-rule: 3px double #666;
    -webkit-column-gap: 40px;
    -webkit-column-rule: 3px double #666;
    column-gap: 40px;
    column-rule: 3px double #666;
}
```

Replacing it with this (the first two have no columns so nothing needed there)

```
@media (max-width: 600px){
    .stdv {display: none;} /* Site menu */
    .LogoBar {display: none;}
    .TitleBar {height: 20px;}
    .PageContent {margin: -40px 0 150px 0;}
    .Logout {padding-left: 0;
             margin-left: 0;}
    div.UpdateDate {display: none;}
    .SetColumns {
        background: inherit;    
        padding: 0 20px 20px 20px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 600px){
    .SetColumns {
        background: inherit;    
        padding: 0 20px 20px 20px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 800px){
.SetColumns {-moz-column-count: 1;
        background: inherit;    
        padding: 0 20px 20px 20px;
        -moz-column-count: 2;
        -moz-column-gap: 40px;
        -moz-column-rule: 3px double #666;
        -webkit-column-count: 2; 
        -webkit-column-gap: 40px;
        -webkit-column-rule: 3px double #666;
        column-count: 2;
        column-gap: 40px;
        column-rule: 3px double #666;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1024px){
    .SetColumns {
        -moz-column-count: 1;
        background: inherit;    
        padding: 0 20px 20px 20px;
        -moz-column-count: 3;
        -moz-column-gap: 40px;
        -moz-column-rule: 3px double #666;
        -webkit-column-count: 3; 
        -webkit-column-gap: 40px;
        -webkit-column-rule: 3px double #666;
        column-count: 3;
        column-gap: 40px;
        column-rule: 3px double #666;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1500px){
    .SetColumns {-moz-column-count: 1;
        background: inherit;    
        padding: 0 20px 20px 20px;
        -moz-column-count: 4;
        -moz-column-gap: 40px;
        -moz-column-rule: 3px double #666;
        -webkit-column-count: 4; 
        -webkit-column-gap: 40px;
        -webkit-column-rule: 3px double #666;
        column-count: 4;
        column-gap: 40px;
        column-rule: 3px double #666;
    }
}
```

Comment: You use wrong structure of media query. It should be `@media (min-width: @screen) and (max-width: @screen) { ... }`

Comment: Thank you. That structure was from w3schools.com as it's something I've not used much before. How do you specify the screen size using the structure that you suggested?

Comment: for ex: `@media (min-width: 350px) and (max-width: 750px) { ... }` or `@media (min-width: 350px)  {....}`

Comment: I took out the "only screen and" leaving only media (max-width: 415px){ . . . } as suggested but still no columns. At least the media only screen and (max-width: 415px) was working because the elements other than the columns were there so there must be something else causing the issue. Sorry, I had to leave off the AT symbols as they won't work here.

Comment: I think that part of the problem was that I had confused min and max so now the columns are sorted out and working. Back to the original question, why does it now ignore the styles set by the default .SetColumns { . . . } class in favor of the .SetColumns {} class setting within media? I was under the impression that setting two class calls to a class of a given name but using different parameters would append to one another.

Comment: Can you update your html?. So we can easy to find solution.

Comment: And please check with `(max-width: 1024px`. It should be `(max-width: 1024px)`. You are missing `(`